# how to subsort a table by more than one column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a a sorting method described by ryan bates in his railcast #228: http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Now my table is sorted by grant_id by default. I would like for a subsorting to take place which means that the default sorting would be by grant_id and then by student_id:
if I have 3 entries. 2 by one student and anther entry by a different student. (all have the same grant).
I would like for the 2 entries by the same student be sorted next to each other.
this is the code I used:
in applcation_helper:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= colum.titleize
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
end
```

in controller:

```
def sort_column
  Entry.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "grant_id"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end

@entries = current_user.entries.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify sorting order for each column:

```
@entries = current_user.entries.order("grant_id ASC, student_id DESC")
```